# LGT8F328P-SSOP20 arduino clone and SPI

Tags: interface, arduino, clone, spi, arduino-ide

LGT8F328P clone  I Would like to use the SPI interface.

as indicated on the datasheet:

[image: LGT8F328P datasheet]
It has everything necessary  but I don't know how to configure <SPI.h>.
and how to make it works for example with W5500?

Comment: what is your actual problem? If this is a clone, using SPI should be the same as on the original. at least if you have the correct board setup. why do you want to edit SPI.h?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, using LGT8F328P-SSOP20 there are two pins  identical!
the MOSI on 11 and SS on  10.

in this way I cannot communicate with SPI protocol.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:
https://github.com/dbuezas/lgt8fx/issues/54
Somebody else got SPI working on the SSOP20 package by overriding the default pin IO direction of PB0

Answer (score 0):

For W5500 chip, you can using ethernet2 library. Edit the ethernet2.h file for replacing w5500_cspin to 9.

```
  EthernetClass() { _dhcp = NULL; w5500_cspin = 9; } //default 10
  void init(uint8_t _cspin = 9) { w5500_cspin = _cspin; }
```

This is specially for **LGT8F328P-SSOP20**